Expo App Crash After APK Build - Works Fine in Expo Go
My Expo app works perfectly in both development and production mode on Expo Go. However, after building the APK and installing it, the app crashes on launch. I ran expo doctor and found no issues. Everything appears fine, but the app still crashes. Any ideas on how to resolve this?
Here is my app.json code
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "newsapp",
    "slug": "newsapp",
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon_app.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "jsEngine": "hermes",
      "permissions": [
        "INTERNET",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "CAMERA"
      ],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon_app.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.godx_rex.newsapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/icon_app.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": ""
      }
    }
  }
}

and the eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 12.5.2",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

